# Database User Securables Question

Tags: sql-server-2016

Learning sql server over here and I'm trying to figure out how to see the securable permissions I have added via T-SQL , in SSMS

For example, I have a database user called "LoginUser1" in Database1 and I granted "grant create table, create view to LoginUser1".

I'm trying to see this permission in SSMS. I go to the properties for the user in this database but i'm not seeing anything. What am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Query presented by @S4V1N will do the trick. If you have to see it via GUI using SSMS you can select:

Database → Properties → Permissions → Select the user `LoginUser1` from `Users or roles:` list.

Select Explicit, you will see this.

[image]

Select Effective, you will see this.

[image]

Comment: @cspell  you are welcome. Do you mind accept it as an answer so other users can be benefited?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

```
SELECT
   ISNULL(OBJECT_NAME(major_id),'') [Objects], USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id) as [UserName], permission_name as [PermissionName]
FROM
    sys.database_permissions p
WHERE grantee_principal_id>0
ORDER BY
    OBJECT_NAME(major_id), USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id), permission_name
```

Comment: I would add a where clause to limit the result set for `LoginUser1`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm all about the sql, I was just trying to see where this is in the GUI